# Android Room.databaseBuilder().createFromFile() silently failing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I currently have the following working code to import an existing user-chosen SQLite db file from the device into my app, which already had a db:

```
    // here goes code to .close() the app's db if isOpen()
    // val userChosenUri: Uri? = data?.data

    val outStream = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).outputStream()
    val inStream = userChosenUri.toString().let {
        userChosenUri?.let { it1 ->
            contentResolver.openInputStream(
                it1
            )
        }
    }

    inStream.use { input ->
        outStream.use { output ->
            if (output != null) {
                input?.copyTo(output)
            } 
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to replace it with code I found on the Android Room guide:

```
    Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
        .createFromFile(File(userChosenUri!!.path))
        .build()
```

But this last snippet doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't crash, but it also doesn't replace the db.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Does the database already exist at the time you are executing that second code snippet?

Comment: Yes, it exists, I've modified the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `createFromFile()` only creates the database from the file if the database does not already exist. If you want to use this for an import or restore-from-backup scenario, I think that you would need to close and delete the existing database before trying to use your latter code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find a Room api method to delete the db, and the solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859778/how-do-i-delete-the-file-of-an-android-room-database) defeat my purpose of trying to simplify the code. I guess will stick with the snippet I have. It seems strange that there is no built-in support for importing/exporting. It's the first thing I wanted to do when I started using this api.